# Hard drive not showing up in disk management

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, storage-spaces

I have the following setup:

- main Windows 10 installation on SSD drive
- two 8TB drives for data storage, set up with Storage Spaces in mirror mode for redundancy (8TB usable out of 16TB total space)

After some issues with Windows not starting, it ran a "self diagnosis" on startup, which took about 8 hours, and in the end seemed to have repaired itself and booted up normally.

However, I lost access to my 8TB drives. After moving them both to the main SATA ports (they were previously on secondary ASMedia SATA ports on my Asus motherboard), reinstalling Windows 10 entirely on a new SSD drive, and reinstalling motherboard and chipset drivers, I still can't see the drive in Disk Management. They only show up in Device Manager.

[image: Disk management and device manager]

Both drives are identical, brand new (bought 2 months ago), so I have trouble believing they both failed at the same time. I believe it is a software issue. Maybe Windows did something to the Storage Spaces while doing its self-repair.

How can I retrieve the data from these drives?

Comment: Does anything show up in the Storage Spaces section of the Control Panel?

Comment: No it's empty. First step is getting it in disk management before storage spaces can use it.